# Can a JavaScript function know its own name, including object it is contained within

Tags: javascript

I need a number of JavaScript functions to know their own names, including the object they are contained within.  I can't seem to find a way to do this.  All the examples on SO don't quite fit my use case.  Here is a fiddle of what I'm looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/amczpro7/5/

```
window.myMainNameSpace = {};

myMainNameSpace.y = {
    z: function(funcToCall) {
        var x = eval("new " + funcToCall);
    }
}

myMainNameSpace.a = {
    b: function(args) {
        alert('I want to alert: myMainNameSpace.a.b');

        /*
        var myName = arguments.callee.toString();
        myName = myName.substr('function '.length);
        myName = myName.substr(0, myName.indexOf('('));
        alert(myName);

        console.log(arguments.callee);
        console.log(this.constructor);
        console.log(this.name);
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.constructor.toString());
        */
    }
}

myMainNameSpace.y.z('myMainNameSpace.a.b({arg1:123})');
```

I would like to be able to make a function that would return `myMainNameSpace.a.b` or `myMainNameSpace.a.b()` so that I could place it in a handful of functions.  Is this possible?  Thanks!

Comment: You mean [`function.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)?

Comment: What you're asking about is a form of reflection. The short answer is "no". The longer answer is "yes, but you don't want to do that." `Eval` is evil, etc etc. Minification/obfuscation will destroy it, etc etc.

Comment: @Blazemonger `function.name` isn't supported everywhere, and won't work on anonymous functions like `b: function(args) {`

Comment: What would happen if the function was contained within multiple objects? That's also a reason why you can't know an object's "name".

Comment: you can iterate globals like you define, and find AN object that has your method, but not to know that it's THE object...

Comment: Thanks all for the comments so far.  I started a different question about the `eval` since this OP was for something else.  Here it is in case you'd like to help.  Thanks!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28098239/eval-vs-if-statements-many-if-statements

Answer (score 0):

You could do it without eval, you just have to iterate over each letter until aimSign is reached. In each iteration you put a new object within last nested object:

```
function callObjTail(obj){

  var lastObj;
  var lastSign;

  for(var i='a'.charCodeAt(); true; i++){
    console.log(i);

    if(obj[String.fromCharCode(i)]){
      lastObj = obj;
      lastSign = i;
      obj = obj[String.fromCharCode(i)];
    }
    else{
      break;
    }


  }

  if(lastObj){
    lastObj[String.fromCharCode(lastSign)]();
  }
  else{
    obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]]();
  }

}
function buildObj(aimSign){

  var obj = {};
  var head = obj;

  var nests = '';
  for(var i='a'.charCodeAt(); i < aimSign.charCodeAt(); i++){

    obj[String.fromCharCode(i)] = {};
    obj = obj[String.fromCharCode(i)];

  }

  return { head : head, tail: obj };

}

var obj = buildObj('e'); 
console.log(obj.head); // { a: { b: { c: { d: {}}}}

console.log(obj);


obj.tail.e = function(){ console.log('tail called');};
console.log(obj.head.a.b.c.d.e());
console.log(obj.tail.e());

// call tail at the end
callObjTail(obj.head);
callObjTail(obj.tail);
```

Comment: I have no idea which "it" (that can be done without eval) this answer refers to. What is your `buildObj` doing? Where is OP talking about letters and aimsigns?

Comment: You are right, I've put some other function into my answer.

Comment: Hm, I still have no idea what these charcode iterations have to do with the OP's question? If they are only used for example, they should be less prominent.

Comment: You are right again. Actualy my concentration was on the question-request at the end and in terms of no need of calling eval.