# Eval vs IF statements (many IF statements)

Tags: javascript, eval

This fiddle pretty much explains what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to find the simplest way to go about coding something WITHOUT using `eval`.  I can do it without `eval` but I think I will have to write 1000s of IF statements.  Or is there another way?

http://jsfiddle.net/243rz8eq/9/

HTML

```
Eval way...<br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch('wins.a({x:1})');">Window-A</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch('wins.b({x:1})');">Window-B</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch('wins.c({x:1})');">Window-C</a><br><br>

Non-Eval way.  Requires if statement for each window (there will be thousands).  Or is there a simpler way I'm not seeing?<br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('window_a');">Window-A</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('window_b');">Window-B</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('window_c');">Window-C</a><br><br>
```

JavaScript

```
window.core = {
    launch: function(obj_string) {
        //we init a blank dhtmlxwindow and do some other things here, then...
        var x = eval("new " + obj_string); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
    },
    launch_no_eval: function(id) {
        //we init a blank dhtmlxwindow and do some other things here, then...
        if (id==="window_a") var x = wins.a({x:1}); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
        else if (id==="window_b") var x = wins.b({x:1}); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
        else if (id==="window_c") var x = wins.c({x:1}); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
        //and so on for literally thousands of items.
    }
};

window.wins = {
    a: function(args) {
        //this.myName = 'wins.a'; is used for the help topic.
        //DB contains columns: [item] / [helpurl]
        //Example Data: [wins.a] / [/help/gettingstarted.html]
        //That is why in this previous post (http://stackoverflow.com/q/28096922/3112803)
        //I was wanting to know if a function could know it's own name so I wouldn't
        //have to type this line below for 1000s of items.
        this.myName = 'wins.a';
        console.log('Window-A is now displayed. Use "'+this.myName+'" to make link to help topic.');
    },
    b: function(args) {
        this.myName = 'wins.b';
        console.log('Window-B is now displayed. Use "'+this.myName+'" to make link to help topic.');
    },
    c: function(args) {
        this.myName = 'wins.c';
        console.log('Window-C is now displayed. Use "'+this.myName+'" to make link to help topic.');
    }
};
```

Comment: why don't you use a function that takes arguments? or some kind of object map?

Comment: I don't have control over the links.  They are really not links but a dhtmlxtoolbar.  I can supply only a string for an ID.  So I'm using the actual function name/call as the ID, then just `eval`ing it.

Comment: You should post your code __here__. A fiddle is just a nice-to-have. See [ask]

Comment: so you can pass in anything you want?

Comment: No, just strings.  The "launcher" can only take in strings because it is the ID attribute of a dhtmlxtoolbar button.  That ID gets passed to the "launcher".  That's why I'm currently using `eval`.  Just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to achieve but `wins.a({x:1})` is the same as `wins['a']({x:1})`, so the function can be written as: `funcname: function(id) { var x = win[id]({x:1}) }` and you can then pass in the individual id's (ie, `a`, `b`, etc) into the function.

Comment: People lack judgement, they see eval() and think "Must down vote".. I up voted you. Obviously the question was posted to find a convenient way to avoid using eval().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach would be to re-write the current usage of accessing [object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) via the `dot notation` and use the `bracket notation` instead.

```
launch_no_eval:function(id) {
        //we init a blank dhtmlxwindow and do some other things here, then...
        if (id==="window_a") var x = wins.a({x:1}); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
        else if (id==="window_b") var x = wins.b({x:1}); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
        else if (id==="window_c") var x = wins.c({x:1}); //fill dhtmlxwindow with proper content
        //and so on for literally thousands of items.
    }
```

could be re-written as follows,

```
launch_no_eval:function(id) { 
        var x = wins[id]({x:1});
}
```

This would mean your HTML markup can change from,

```
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('window_a');">Window-A</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('window_b');">Window-B</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('window_c');">Window-C</a><br><br>
```

to,

```
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('a');">Window-A</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('b');">Window-B</a><br>
<a href="javascript:core.launch_no_eval('c');">Window-C</a><br><br>
```

As Daniel commented below, assuming you have no control over the HTML markup and must use the `window_#` value being passed in then you could perform the following,

```
launch_no_eval:function(id) {
        // replace 'window_' with empty string to retrieve unique id
        var x = wins[id.replace('window_', '')]({x:1});
}
```

Comment: it would be more like `wins[id.replace('window_', '')]({x:1})`

Comment: @DanielWeiner Correct. Assuming the HTML cannot be changed to pass in the unique id in the `window_id` string.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for!  http://jsfiddle.net/243rz8eq/13/  Thanks!  Yeah, I can make the IDs whatever I want, so the replace works or the simpler a,b,c works. Thanks guys.  Forgot about referencing objects that way.  Ugh.

Comment: Just remember: there is almost never any need to use `eval()`. `eval()` is evil.